# For the divisor function $\sigma_k(n)=\sum_{d|n}d^k$, is there any definition for $\sigma_k(0)$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

> For the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) 
>   $$\sigma_k(n)=\sum_{d|n}d^k$$
>   is there any definition for $\sigma_k(0)$?

The reason why I am asking is because I want ot calculate $E_4^2$  , $$E_4=1+240\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma_3(n)q^n $$ using the cauchy product .

Comment: We don't count $0$ here I guess.

Comment: I don't know if this fits very well in a particular formalism, but very naively perhaps it seems that one might guess, since every integer divides 0 we have $\sigma_k(0) = \infty$, at least somewhat roughly, especially if $k$ is even.

Comment: There's a choice for $\sigma_{2k-1}(0)$ (in terms of Bernoulli numbers) which makes $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sigma_{2k-1}(n)q^n$ a modular form, at least for $k\ge4$. See books on modular forms, e.g. Serre's *A Course in Arithmetic*.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. The coefficients of $E_4^2$ are obvious from $E_4=1+240\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma_3(n)q^n$, they are $2 \sigma_3(n) +240^2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sigma_3(k)\sigma_3(n-k)$. If your question is if it makes sense to say $\sigma_3(0) = 1/240$ then the answer is no. The constant term of $E_4/240$ appears from $G_4 = \sum_{n,m} \frac{1}{(nz+m)^4}$, equivalently from the functional equation and the pole of $\zeta(s)\zeta(s-3)$ at $s=1$